# How to extract a SAS record which has the max value for a column

Tags: sql, sas

I have a SAS dataset like this:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4    col5  col6
A1     B1     C1     D1      E1    $100
A1     B1     C1     D2      E2    $200
A2     B2     C2     D3      E3    $500
```

The first 3 columns are my key columns. I need to extract the row that has got the highest value for `col6`.

So I can do:

```
proc sql;
   create table temp as 
   select col1,col2,col3,max(col6) as col6 
   from dataset 
   group by 1,2,3;
   select * from dataset t1 
   inner join temp t2 
   where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 
     and t1.col3 = t2.col3 and t1.col6 = t2.col6;
quit;
```

But how can I achieve the same by making one pass through the data? Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine for many uses.  If using exactly one pass is actually essential, you could use a data step and a hash object.  This reads every record once and updates the single row in the hash object every time it finds a row with a higher col6 than it's yet seen.

```
data _null_;
    if 0 then set have; /*Make sure all vars used in the hash object are set up with the correct types*/
    retain highest_so_far;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        highest_so_far = col6;
        declare hash hi_row();
        hi_row.definekey(co1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);
        hi_row.definedone();
    end;

    set have end=eof;

    if col6 > highest_so_far then do;
        hi_row.clear();
        hi_row.add();
        highest_so_far = col6;
    end;

    if (eof) then hi_row.output(want);
run;
```

If there's a tie for highest, this program would return the first, but it could be modified to return an arbirary number of ties.

Comment: ERROR: Type mismatch for method parameter 6 at line 561 column 1.
ERROR: Expecting Character type.
ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

Comment: Also, I wonder how does this code (if somehow worked) output the required obs by each (col1, col2, col3) group. Can someone explain?

Comment: I've made a slight adjustment that I think should help you avoid the above error.

Answer (score 0):

**data** col;
    input (col1-col5)(:$2.)  col6:comma.;

    cards;

A1     B1     C1     D1      E1     $100
A1     B1     C1     D2      E2     $200
A2     B2     C2     D3      E3      $500
;;;;
    **run**;

**proc** **print**;

    **run**;

**proc** **summary** data=col;
    output out=maxrow idgroup(max(col6) out(_all_)=);
    **run**;

**proc** **print**;

    **run**;